# Using integer math to get a percentage in Rust

Tags: rust, percentage

I have to calculate some percentages but I have to avoid using floats in Rust.

i have this data structure

```rust
let data = Vec<Identity, u64>
```

from this i can sum all the u64's to get a total which we'll call the total maturity

```rust
let total_maturity = data.iter().map(|(,b)| b).sum()
```

so now i have the total maturity across all of them. it should be fairly trivial to get the percentage of maturity for each neuron but how i do i express this.

With floats it would be simple and the resulting vec of percentages associated with a neuron would be like [0.3, 0.4, 0.1 ....]

I've heard of using integer math but im not sure how it really works.

Comment: Integers simply don't have values right of the decimal point, so can't represent those values. What you can do is multiply by multiples of 10, so if you want a percent (between 0 and 100), multiply by 1000 first, then do the divisions. The final digit should be rounded to the nearest 10 (0 to 4 becomes 0, 5 to 9 becomes 10), then you can divide by 10 to get percent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply multiply all your numbers by 100 before dividing them.

```rust
let data: Vec<u64> = vec![3, 4, 1, 2];
let total_maturity: u64 = data.iter().sum();

let percentages: Vec<u64> = data
    .iter()
    .map(|b| b * 100 / total_maturity)
    .collect();

println!("{:?}", percentages);
// [30, 40, 10, 20]
```

If you need more precision, you can multiply by a larger number. Just remember that you will need to reintroduce the decimal point if you ever need to display them or perform math on them.

```rust
let data: Vec<u64> = vec![3, 4, 1, 9992];
let total_maturity: u64 = data.iter().sum();
let percentages: Vec<u64> = data
    .iter()
    .map(|b| b * 10_000 / total_maturity)
    .collect();

let formatted: Vec<String> = percentages
    .iter()
    .map(|&p| {
        let whole = p / 100;
        let frac = p % 100;
        format!("{whole}.{frac:.02}%")
        // or you could convert them to floats
        // format!("{}", p as f32 / 100.0)
    })
    .collect();

println!("{:?}", formatted);
// ["0.3%", "0.4%", "0.1%", "99.92%"]
```

If you want something more flexible, there is the [rust_decimal crate](https://docs.rs/rust_decimal/1.34.2).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. I really appreciate it. I ended up using the `num-bigint` crate and essentially doing what you did but i upped my precision to 0.000001% by multiplying by 100,000,000.

Comment: The last digit won't be accurate - 0.0...01987 will be truncated to 0.0...01 instead of 0.0...02. Just keep that in mind, if it matters then you can add an extra 0 to the initial multiplication, then round the last 2 digits before dividing by 10 for the final result.